# Where does Pidgin display Jabber Away Messages?

Tags: pidgin

Pidgin only displays "Away" or "Extended Away" but not additional message. Where does Pidgin display custom Away Messages?

Answer (score 2):

After you set your status in the statusbox you can inmediatly starty typing your away message, you can also create and save custom status with custom nessages.

Comment: Ok, but where is the away message from buddies displayed?

Comment: In the buddy list window.

Comment: Behind Status "Extended Away"?

Comment: Should the status message be displayed next to "Extended Away"? Or is it anywhere else in the contact list? Do I have to enable it somewhere? http://abload.de/img/pidgin2q3ou2.png